# jQuery get li and innerHtml

Tags: jquery, dom

i am trying to display the li and inner html of li tag.

for example:

```
    <ul class="for">

       <li>line 1</li>
       <li class="second">line 2</li>
       <li>line 3</li>
       <li>line 4</li>

     </ul>
```

i want following output:   line 2

i tried following code but it display only inner html of the li not displaying li tag.

```
         jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $tt = jQuery('li.second').html();
          console.log($tt);
            }
```

output:  line2 .i need help to get following output:  `<li class="second">line 2</li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property

> The outerHTML attribute of the element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

*Use* following to get output: `<li class="second">line 2</li>`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $tt = jQuery('li.second').prop('outerHTML');
    console.log($tt);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/mj2dvLyt/)

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, it really help!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your selected `DOM` element and append with `.html()`.

```
$tt = $("<li>").append($('li.second').clone()).html();
console.log($tt);
```

**output**

```
<li class="second">line 2</li>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsf2u33m/1/)**

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, it really help!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you log this element you can see the all underlying properties of this-

`console.log($('li.second'))`

Here is how it looks-
[image]

Now, note the property `outerHTML` has your needs!
You can now directly call this property as @satpal suggested as-

`$('li.second').prop('outerHTML')`

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, it really help!  Thanks